# Jupyter notebook taking too long

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

My jupyter notebook taking too long to run on this specific code chunk

```
#Running polarity score on whole dataset
res = {}
for i,row in tqdm(df.iterrows(), total = len(df)):
    try :
        text = row["Text"]
        myid = row['Id']
        vader_result = sia.polarity_scores(text)
        vader_result_rename = {}
        for key, value in vader_result.items():
            vader_result_rename[f"vader_{key}"] = value  
        roberta_result = polarity_Scores_roberta(text)
        both = {**vader_result_rename, **roberta_result}
        res[myid] = both
    except RuntimeError:
        print(f"Broke for id {myid}")
```

When I'm running this code it consumes more than 2 hours to calculate the sentiment score for my data set. But when I run samething on kaggle notebook it took less than a minute even I have not selected any accelerator, can any one help me in this matter?

Comment: Is the slowdown the result of `sia.polarity_scores(text)` or `polarity_Scores_roberta(text)` or something else?

Comment: I can't surely say about it as it shows one loading bar

Comment: 3%                    16/500 [05:09<1:20:08, 9.93s/it]

Like this, I can't upload pic in comments at here's no option.